# Java regex split String into an array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have a scanner String input in the following format: 12:00:00PM.

I managed to finally isolate PM or AM by this:

```
public class ConverTime
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String timeString = sc.next();

        String[] pmOrAm = timeString.split("\\d");
        String[] nums = timeString.split("(: + \\D)");

        // PM or AM
        String timeType = pmOrAm[pmOrAm.length - 1];
        for (String n: nums)
        {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

I know the way I isolate PM or AM is not the best, so hopefully there is a better way where i can get an array of exactly one string.

But when I run the for loop for the "nums" array, the output is:

```
 12:00:00PM
```

I want the output to be like so:

```
12
00
00
```

without the "PM" or "AM." How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an easy way could be:

```
timeString.split("(AM|PM|:)")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Although I was looking to do it purely use the split method, this is working too!

Comment: Thank you, that is even much simpler!! I upvoted you but my upvote won't count yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness sake, while there have been good solutions for split and regular expressions, there is another one for your use case...

```
Data date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssaa").parse(s);
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println( data.get(Calendar.HOUR);
System.out.println( data.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
System.out.println( data.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Just as an idea in a different direction, since we are talking about time Strings here, which would allow you to make assumptions about it beyond the pure regular expression format...

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?:[AP]M)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vJ0zE6/2).
Remember to double escape the backslashes in `Java` (ie `\\d+`).

Comment: Are you sure? This out puts nothing on the screen now. I did the following:

        String[] nums = timeString.split("(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?:[AP]M)");

Comment: @NishaShlaymoon: with `.split()`, you can even use the colon.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to use `String[] nums = timeString.split(":");`
and to output each index it would be something like `System.out.println(nums[0]); , nums[1] and nums[2]` and to remove AM/PM you can do `String removeap = nums[2].substring(0, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

I think more correct way is to use regular expression here rather than split. This way you can detect if you get unexpected inputs rather than having the string processed incorrectly.

```
    String s = "12:01:02PM";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\w\\w");
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(s);

    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        // Handle error...
    }

    int hh = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
    int mm = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
    int ss = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(3));

    System.out.println(hh + ", " + mm + ", " + ss);
```